# logstash 2.4.0: grok fails silently on custom patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying (and failing) in getting custom patterns to work with logstash 2.4.0. Here is the relevant part of the conf file:

```
#some parsing happens above...
    grok {
       patterns_dir => ["/config_dir/patterns"]
       match => [ "syslog_message", "%{QID:qid}:" ]
    }
```

(full config is at the end) - the patterns directory contains only the file sendmail.grok:

```
#########
QID a
```

Running this I get (reformatted exception):

```
{:exception=>"Grok::PatternError",
 :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-grok-0.11.3/lib/grok-pure.rb:123:in `compile'",
              "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1479:in `loop'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-grok-0.11.3/lib/grok-pure.rb:93:in `compile'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:264:in `register'",
              "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:259:in `register'",
              "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:255:in `register'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:182:in `start_workers'",
              "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:182:in `start_workers'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'",
              "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"],
 :level=>:error,
 :file=>"logstash/agent.rb",
 :line=>"493",
 :method=>"start_pipeline"
}
```

This exception is invariant with the contents of the patterns/sendmail.grok. It is a PatternError, but it does not tell me  where/why the error happens. If , however, I comment the match line out, everything is just fine (sample otput below):

```
{
                 "message" => "Oct 25 13:18:27 alpha opendkim[1160]: u9PBIMwu011394: authsmtp79.register.it [195.110.122.164] not internal",
                "@version" => "1",
              "@timestamp" => "2016-10-25T11:25:35.072Z",
                    "path" => "/log/maillog",
                    "host" => "93fe70f98023",
    "syslog_severity_code" => 5,
    "syslog_facility_code" => 1,
         "syslog_facility" => "user-level",
         "syslog_severity" => "notice",
                    "tags" => [
        [0] "syslog_message_unparsed",
        [1] "syslog_relay"
    ],
        "syslog_timestamp" => "Oct 25 13:18:27",
             "syslog_host" => "alpha",
                 "program" => "opendkim",
                     "pid" => "1160",
          "syslog_message" => "u9PBIMwu011394: authsmtp79.register.it [195.110.122.164] not internal",
         "syslog_fullhost" => "alpha"
}
```

Ideas?

TIA,
alf

**Full configuration:**

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/log/maillog"
    }
}

filter {
  syslog_pri {
  }
  mutate {
    add_tag => [ "syslog_parsefailure", "syslog_message_unparsed" ]
  }

  grok {
     match => [ "message", "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:syslog_host} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" ]
    add_field => { "syslog_fullhost" => "%{syslog_host}" }
    add_tag => [ "syslog_relay" ]
    remove_tag => [ "syslog_parsefailure" ]
    tag_on_failure => [ ]
  }

  if [program] == "sendmail" {
     mutate {
      add_tag => [ "sendmail_log" ]
     }
     grok {
       patterns_dir => ["/config_dir/patterns"]
       match => [ "syslog_message", "%{QID:qid}:" ]
     }
 }

}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with the `grok` filter match I believe as the per the exception. Could you please change your match as this and check:

```
grok {
        patterns_dir => [""]
        match => { "message" => "" }            
    }
```

You could try testing your grok filters [here](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), before you actually use them in the conf file.

Source: [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it appears something was wrong with the environment hosting my docker container (a CentOS7 VM). I rebuilt the same exact environment on an FC24 (non-VM) machine (newer docker, same containers, etc.) and the exception just disappeared.

Lessons learned:

- The dream of liberating oneself from environment dependencies through containerisation is, on the face of it, a delusion. Ghost bugs/execptions can - and do - appear due to the container host environment, without telling you much about it, and being therefore more elusive than ever.
- Logstash (well gork's) exception logging is less than ideal. Whatever was causing the original exception (if I had to bet, I'd bet file system and/or SELinux problems, but I really still don't know) was most emphatically **not** a pattern problem

Thanks to all who <strike>bothered to (even) read</strike> wasted time on this.